# jQuery - create Radiobuttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a radiobutton by myselfe. I am creating the style with jQuery and the technique with php. My problem is the style. I want to click on the first button and then it should be blue and if I click on the second button then the second button should be blue and the first button should be white.
My problem is, that the backgroundcolor does never change.
I know, that the variables are okay (I watched in the console). They change! But the background color doesn't.
I would be very thankfull if somebody could help me!!!
Thank you!!!

HTML:

```
<table class="radiobutton_table" id="radiobutton_table-id">
    <tr class="radiobutton_table-tr" id="radiobutton_table-tr-id">
        <td class="radiobutton_table-tr-td radiobutton_one" id="radiobutton_true">
            <span class="radiobutton-text" id="radiobutton-text-True">True</span>
        </td>
        <td class="radiobutton_table-tr-td radiobutton_two" id="radiobutton_false">
            <span class="radiobutton-text" id="radiobutton-text-False">False</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
[![var button_1 = false;
var button_2 = false;

$(document).ready(function() {

    if($('#radiobutton_true').click(function() {

        button_1 = true;

        if(button_2 == true) {
            button_2 = false;
        }

    }))

    if($('#radiobutton_false').click(function() {

        button_2 = true;

        if(button_1 == true) {
            button_1 = false;
        }

    }))

    while(button_1 == true) {

        $('#radiobutton_true').css({"background-color": "blue"});
        $('#radiobutton_false').css({"background-color": "white"});

    }

    while(button_2 == true) {

        $('#radiobutton_false').css({"background-color": "blue"});
        $('#radiobutton_true').css({"background-color": "white"});

    }
    })][1]][1]
```

Comment: why would you have 2 while loops here? can you share a your fiddle?

Comment: You have some very strange flow-control.  Why the `if` around the click, and why the `while` loops that appear to never exit?

Comment: You have two (possibly infinite or never ran) while loops. I'm quite certain you don't want to do that. You will want to make them `if-else if` and place it in a event handler for `onchange` (or move them into your current click events).

Comment: Your `while` loops are infinite loops. Javascript is single-threaded, so event handlers can't run while the loops are running, so the variables will never change.

Comment: I tryed it with if else if and with onchange. But it doesn't work eather

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the style changes inside the `.click` handlers, not use `if` or `while`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#radiobutton_true').click(function() {

    $('#radiobutton_true').css({
      "background-color": "blue"
    });
    $('#radiobutton_false').css({
      "background-color": "white"
    });
  });

  $('#radiobutton_false').click(function() {

    $('#radiobutton_false').css({
      "background-color": "blue"
    });
    $('#radiobutton_true').css({
      "background-color": "white"
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="radiobutton_table" id="radiobutton_table-id">
  <tr class="radiobutton_table-tr" id="radiobutton_table-tr-id">
    <td class="radiobutton_table-tr-td radiobutton_one" id="radiobutton_true">
      <span class="radiobutton-text" id="radiobutton-text-True">True</span>
    </td>
    <td class="radiobutton_table-tr-td radiobutton_two" id="radiobutton_false">
      <span class="radiobutton-text" id="radiobutton-text-False">False</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```